# get list of arguments from a function created from a string

Tags: javascript

This may be a bizarre question but I'm curious as to if it can work. I have the following JavaScript function:

```
function createPerson(args){
  alert(args.firstName);

  if (args.surname){
    alert(args.surname);
  }
}
```

Then the following (e.g. a scenario in which the function is stored as a string):

```
var functionAsString = 'createPerson({ firstName: \'John\' });';
var convertFunction = new Function(functionAsString);
convertFunction();
```

This alerts "John" as expected. What I would then like to try and do is add a surname to the arguments before executing it, like this (but not garbage!):

```
convertFunction.arguments.surname = 'Smith';
convertFunction();
```

I've yet to find a way to grab the object in the function's arguments in order to modify it. Does anyone know if something like this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: When you find yourself wanting to do something that seems "bizarre" or unnatural, there's a good possibility that somewhere along the way you made a questionable design decision.

Comment: This is a bizarre idea and I don't know of any way it can be done. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I was just experimenting really, but one example would be if a function was stored as a string in a database field. I know this is probably blasphemy :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.

Take a closer look at the `convertFunction` variable:

```
var functionAsString = 'createPerson({ firstName: \'John\' });';
var convertFunction = new Function(functionAsString);
console.log(convertFunction)
// function anonymous() {
// createPerson({ firstName: 'John' });
// }
```

As you can see, the `convertFunction` is not your function directly - it is an anonymous wrapper, that takes no arguments and calls your function with pre-defined arguments.

Comment: Gotcha. This makes sense and explains why every attempt I've made to retrieve the arguments has failed! Thanks for the response.